# Handlebars - How to use a Path in the #if

Tags: handlebars.js

I am trying to setup a #if conditional for a nested path but cannot seem to get it to work. I have tried the following:

```
{{#if person.showName}}

{{#if person/showName}}

{{#if (lookup person 'showName')}}
```

But cannot get it to go into the if branch. The object is setup as this:

```
{
  person {
    firstName: 'Uncle',
    lastName: 'Bob',
    showName: true
  }
}
```

Is this something that is just not supported within handlebars for the basic if conditional check? I would like to avoid using a `{{#with}}` or flattening all of the "flags" down to the base object.

Comment: `{{#if person.showName}}` should be just fine. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/1xd84pru/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a `{{#with}}` commented out in the HTML but it was apparently still getting executed even though it was commented out. As I am new to using Handlebars, it is a learning experience.